# Is a dream analysis assur today?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, modern-times, dream

We all know Yoseff did dream analysis (baker and wine guy) but he had a special connection to Hashem.

Lets say you went for a dream analysis in modern times; would it be [assur](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/591/5323)? Is it considered *avodah zorah* (idol worship), or some other prohibition?

Comment: For possibly relevant prohibitions, see Sefer Hamitsot (negative commandments #31). Regarding acting on such a "reading" see #33.

Comment: probably more significant than some connection to Hashem, is the fact that Yossef was not obligated to follow the Torah; we are.

Comment: Rabbis in the time of the Talmud went for dream analysis (e.g. 9th perek of Brachot).

Comment: Why do you think it's Avodah Zarah?

Comment: Siddur Beis Yaakov (from Rabbi Yaakov M'Emden) has a whole section on *pisron chalomos* (interpretation of dreams).